# R: subset of character vector

Tags: r, vector, element

I want to get a subset from a character vector. However I want to obtain vector2 containing elements from initial vector between specific elements.

```
vector <- c("a", "", "b", "c","","d", "e")
vector
```

how to grab all elements between elements "b" and "e" and get vector2?

```
#Expected result:
vector2
"c","","d"
```

Comment: Literal (not robust): `vector[ (1+match("b", vector)):(-1+match("e", vector)) ]`, there are likely more-robust methods that handle missingness, mid-ordering, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also do something like this:

```
vector <- c("a", "", "b", "c","","d", "e")
vector[seq(which(vector=="b")+1,which(vector=="e")-1)]
#[1] "c" ""  "d"
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is one option

```
f <- function(x, left, right) {
  idx <- x %in% c(left, right)
  x[as.logical(cumsum(idx) * !idx)]
}

f(vector, "b", "e")
# [1] "c" ""  "d"
```

The first step is to calculate `idx` as

```
vector %in% c("b", "e")
# [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

then calculate the cumulative sum

```
cumsum(vector %in% c("b", "e"))
# [1] 0 0 1 1 1 1 2
```

multiply by `!vector %in% c("b", "e")` which gives

```
cumsum(vector %in% c("b", "e")) * !vector %in% c("b", "e")
# [1] 0 0 0 1 1 1 0
```

convert to this to a logical vector and use it to subset `x`.

---

For the given example another option is `charmatch`

```
x <- charmatch(c("b", "e"), vector) + c(1, -1)
vector[seq.int(x[1], x[2])]
# [1] "c" ""  "d"
```

Answer (score 0):

With negative subscripts:

```
x[-c(1:which(x == 'b'), which(x =='e'):length(x))]
#[1] "c" ""  "d"
```

In case when `e` is found before `b` it returns empty vector:

```
(y <- rev(x))
#[1] "e" "d" ""  "c" "b" ""  "a"
y[-c(1:which(y == 'b'), which(y =='e'):length(y))]
#character(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try:

```
vector[cumsum(vector %in% c("b", "e")) == 1][-1]

[1] "c" ""  "d"
```